# <td> widths being different when in different <tr>s

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was looking as [this JFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxbk81h/).

```css
.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.mytable-head {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.mytable-head td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mytable-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.mytable-body td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}

.mytable-footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.mytable-footer td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable mytable-head">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">25</td>
    <td width="50%">50</td>
    <td width="25%">25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="mytable mytable-body">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">50</td>
    <td width="30%">30</td>
    <td width="20%">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="mytable mytable-body">
  <tr>
    <td width="16%">16</td>
    <td width="68%">68</td>
    <td width="16%">16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="mytable mytable-footer">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">20</td>
    <td width="30%">30</td>
    <td width="50%">50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I noticed that after each `<tr>` a new table started. Can I do something like this and not have to start a new table?

```
<table class="mytable mytable-head">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">25</td>
    <td width="50%">50</td>
    <td width="25%">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">50</td>
    <td width="30%">30</td>
    <td width="20%">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a simple way for this or should I start a new table every time?

Comment: How is it still a table if the rows and columns don't line up? Why would you use a table for such a thing?

Comment: Using colspan might work depending on how precisely you need to make the widths

Comment: I’m doing a messaging system. So if the user logged in sent the message I want the first <tr> to be 25% and the second to be 75% and vise versa if the user is receiving the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I was wondering if I could do something like this

No. Not with a table. Its bad form to use a table for layout - stick to using it for tabular data and use something more appropriate for the layout of your messaging system like flexbox:

```css
.messages {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.messages blockquote {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
}

.messages blockquote cite {
  flex-grow: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-self: center;
}

.messages blockquote p {
  max-width: 70%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.messages .sender {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <blockquote class="sender">
    <cite>Bob</cite>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut volutpat lobortis sem non gravida.</p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote class="recipient">
    <cite>Alice</cite>
    <p>Etiam dignissim nisi quam, eget tempus enim placerat sed. Integer et nulla nisl. </p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote class="sender">
    <cite>Bob</cite>
    <p>Aliquam eu est eget urna imperdiet accumsan. Cras sit amet tortor et enim feugiat blandit.</p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote class="recipient">
    <cite>Alice</cite>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </blockquote>
  <blockquote class="sender">
    <cite>Bob</cite>
    <p>Ut in dui in lectus maximus dapibus id ut sapien. Nulla feugiat arcu nec metus gravida mattis.</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want column alignment to vary, I suggest using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
You can set the [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) for columns in each type of row.

For example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container span {
  outline:1px solid black;
}

.container.row1 span {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.container.row2 span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.container.row3 span {
  background-color: thistle;
}

.row1 span:nth-child(1),
.row1 span:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.row1 span:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.row2 span:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.row2 span:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
.row2 span:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.row3 span:nth-child(1),
.row3 span:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 16%;
}
.row3 span:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 68%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row1">
  <span>25</span>
  <span>50</span>
  <span>25</span>
</div>

<div class="container row2">
  <span>50</span>
  <span>30</span>
  <span>20</span>
</div>

<div class="container row1">
  <span>25</span>
  <span>50</span>
  <span>25</span>
</div>

<div class="container row2">
  <span>50</span>
  <span>30</span>
  <span>20</span>
</div>

<div class="container row3">
  <span>16</span>
  <span>68</span>
  <span>16</span>
</div>

<div class="container row1">
  <span>25</span>
  <span>50</span>
  <span>25</span>
</div>

<div class="container row2">
  <span>50</span>
  <span>30</span>
  <span>20</span>
</div>

<div class="container row3">
  <span>16</span>
  <span>68</span>
  <span>16</span>
</div>
```